# Qt Creator не обрабатывает проект

Tags: qt5, windows-10, qtcreator

Скачал Qt 5.10.0, потом 5.10.1 в Windows 10. В обоих случаях Creator не может построить проект, предлагая настроить "комплект", не объясняя, что это такое.

В окне настройки:

```
Тип устройства: Desktop
Устройство: Локальный ПК
Sysroot - пусто
Компиляторы C и C++: Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 9.0 (x86)
Отладчик: Не задан
Профиль Qt: Отсутствует
Qt mkspec и Утилита CMake - пусто
Генератор CMake: <нет> - <нет>
Платформа: <нет>
Инструментарий: <нет>
```

Что надо сделать, чтобы Creator смог работать?

Comment: Попробую вам помочь, хоть за Qt Creator садился 100500 лет назад :) Профиль Qt -- это сам Qt на вашем компьютере. У вас будет 2 профиля для Qt 5.10.0 и 5.10.1. На вкладке профилей можно создать или настроить профили. После установки Qt, они должны автоматически появиться в профилях, если их нет, тогда нужно будет создать профиль и в нем указать путь до qmake.exe, который находится в конкретной папке Qt. Поэтому, в настройках тыкните на профиль Qt и выберите существующий, если он есть, иначе создайте.

Answer (score 1):

Вы поставили только IDE(Qt Creator) голый. Qt Creator это всего лишь оболочка.
И так действия:

1. Снеси Всё.
2. Скачай: https://www.qt.io/download.
3. Затем при установке поставь все галочки(Потом разберёшься не нужное тебе удалишь).
4. Загрузит гигов 20.И всё должно работать.Радуемся и незабываем плюсовать:)

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/272758)

Comment: Сам сначала столкнулся с этой проблемой, написал простое ришення.Чем вам не нравится мой ответ?